# vuejs component array push watcher

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

confusing title, I wasn't sure how else to write it. 
So i have a component and it accepts a prop which is an array. 
What i am looking to do, is on array.push() i would like a function to trigger for that array element.

so it is an alert toast message, and i want it to stay up for 3 seconds. so i was thinking about something like

```
watch: {
    arrayObj: function () {
        let self = this
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.dismiss(this.id)
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```

but i think i may be missing something here. How do i get the latest pushed object's reference so i make sure the dismiss method calls the correct alert? Is watch even the correct way to go about this?

Comment: `var last = this[ this.length-1 ]` ?

Comment: but that would give me out of bounds exception when dismiss() is called becasue the array object wouldn't exist and it is still the watched being called

Comment: Are any other array operations possible? Slice? Pop?

Comment: And why exactly would you want to do it like this? This seems more like a code smell than an actual problem with javascript or vue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what behavior you're trying to get, but it seems to me that you need to keep track of the latest pushed item and pass that to your component. The component would watch `latestPushed` and act accordingly.

If the latest pushed item could be repeated, you would not see a change when a duplicate value is pushed. In that case, it makes sense to pass an event bus prop to the component and send and event when the parent pushes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bus: new Vue(),
    theArray: [1]
  },
  methods: {
    push() {
      const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      this.theArray.push(value);
      this.bus.$emit('push', value);
    }
  },
  components: {
    toasterNote: {
      props: ['bus'],
      data() {
        return {
          active: false,
          latestPush: null,
          timer: null
        };
      },
      created() {
        this.bus.$on('push', (newValue) => {
          this.latestPush = newValue;
          this.active = true;
          clearTimeout(this.timer);
          this.timer = setTimeout(() => this.active = false, 3000);
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>{{theArray}}</div>
  <button @click="push">Push</button>
  <toaster-note inline-template :bus="bus">
    <div v-if="active">
      You pushed {{latestPush}}
    </div>
  </toaster-note>
</div>
```